# working with php and python together

Tags: php, python, mysql, excel

currently i am working on a project which is related to automation.

I am using php and mysql for my work. I have to make a code in php which can import, export and edit the excel file and the extension of excel file is .xlsm. As i have tried my best, but i didn't succeed with the .xlsm file.
so, one of my friend has suggest me that in python, you can do that.

so, is it possible, if i insert the python script(which can import, export and edit the .xlsm file) into the php code and the run the code. please let me know, will this work. if this work then how?

Comment: use exec() to run the python script from php

Comment: @meh is right, just make an answer with link http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: well, i am trying to modify the source code of sugarcrm ce...in sugarcrm ce, only .csv file can be import, export and edit.  so, i want to modify the code in such a way that i can import, export and edit the .xlsm file. and i think, right now, it is not possible with php  alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to execute an external program in PHP.

Comment: i know about the exec(), but my question is will it work with the .xlms file

Comment: **'If i insert the python script(which can import, export and edit the .xlsm file) into the php code and the run the code. please let me know, will this work. if this work then how?'** Then what was this?  The answer specifies a method by which you can run the python file from php.

Comment: i have tried to upvote your answer, but it is displaying: "Thanks for the feedback ! once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your vote will change the publicly-displayed post score "....i think right now i cannot upvote your answer, as i am new user